# Added podspec to trunk but the site is not showing my pod correctly

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I pushed my podspec to trunk today, second time total, but first time as a swift library. Github is [here](https://github.com/SpriteKitAlliance/SKAButton). If i search cocoapods.org I can see my other pod and this pod, but they act differently on the site. SKAToolKit you can expand and look at on the site, where SKAButton you can click to go to our homepage, and it is also listed ~20 times in the search results. https://cocoapods.org/?q=SKAToolkit

My cocoapods version is 0.38.2.

Lastly, in the documentation section there is an error on the left side. "Error Parsing Pod: Could not find objective-c classes".

Again it parsed correctly, and I can pull it correctly, just not showing up correctly on the site, nor did I get a mention in the tweet feed, though did end up in the RSS feed.

Am I doing something wrong in the podspec or is this a site issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got a same issue. But after wating some hours it worked. I think it takes some time to route to your pod in search. Better wait some time.